# Long table with varying columns (landscape and page fitting)

Tags: tables, color, longtable, columns, landscape

I want to have a long table that looks like as follows:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Issue}}}                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Findings}}}                                              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Theme 1}}}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Name of Theme 1}}}                                       \\ \hline
Project 1                   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam,nonumy eirmod.                                                                              & MS 1: & Vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan,et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum \\ \hline
                            &                                                                                                                                                               & MS 2: & Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation                                                                   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                            &                                                                                                                                                               & MS 3: & Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse,molestie consequat                                    \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{Project 2} & \multirow{-3}{*}{At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita,kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.} & MS 4: & Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.                                                                    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Theme 2}}                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Name of Theme 2}}                                                              \\ \hline
Project 3                   & Ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea,commodo consequat.                                                                                        & MS 5: & Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna,aliquyam erat.                                            \\ \hline
Project 4                   & Justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren                                                                                                      & MS 6: & Dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis,dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Theme 3}}                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Name of Theme 3}}                                                              \\ \hline
Project 5                   & Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt,ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.                                                  & MS 7: & Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil,imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, this does not look like the table I want to have. Can anybody help me?

Comment: you say longtable and tagged the question that way but your example does not use `longtable` do you need this table to take more than one page?  for the columns you have `llll` but beed `lp{3cm}lp{3cm}` (or some other width) so columns 2 and 4 take paragraphs of text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

- since you not provided *mwe* -- a small complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` i guess what is in your document preamble and how is defined page layout
- for cells with multi lines content you need to define column type `p{...}` or `X` from package `tabularx`
- for multi row cells with multi lines content you need to define its width.   **recent version** of `multirow` package offer option `{=}` which overtake column format.
- i assume, that in multi row cells you like to have text in cells on their top. for this positioning is used option `[t]` also defined in the recent version of `multirow` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|L|l|L|}
    \hhline{|--|--|}
    \rowcolor{black}
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\color{white} \textbf{Issue}}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\color{white} \textbf{Findings}}    \\
    \hhline{|--|--|}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Theme 1}}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Name of Theme 1}}           \\
    \hhline{|--|--|}
Project 1
    &   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
        sed diam,nonumy eirmod.                                                                              & MS 1: &   Vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero
                    eros et accumsan, et iusto odio dignissim qui
                    blandit praesent luptatum                       \\ \hline
\multirow[t]{10}{*}{Project 2}
    & \multirow[t]{10}{=}{At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                        et ea rebum. Stet clita,kasd gubergren,
                        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet.}
        & MS 2: &   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exerci tation                      \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & MS 3: &   Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit
                    in vulputate velit esse,molestie consequat      \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & MS 4: &   Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
                    sanctus est.                                    \\
    \hhline{|--|--|}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Theme 2}}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Name of Theme 2}}               \\
    \hhline{|--|--|}
Project 3
    &   Ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea,
        commodo consequat.                                                                                        & MS 5: &   Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
                    et dolore magna, aliquyam erat.                 \\ \hline
Project 4
    &   Justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren
        & MS 6: &   Dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum
                    zzril delenit augue duis,dolore te feugait
                    nulla facilisi.                                 \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Theme 3}}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Name of Theme 3}}               \\ \hline
Project 5
    &   Consetetur sadipscing elitr,
        sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt,
        ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.                                                  & MS 7: &   Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option
                    congue nihil, imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat
                    facer possim assum.                             \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

**note:** 
i above *mwe* i consider your *mwe* and not "longtable" tag of your question. recent version of `multirow` package is *release 2016/11/25, version v2.2*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Zarko! However, if I comply your solution in a fresh document, I get a "Missing number, treated as zero. \end{tabularx}" as well as "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{tabularx}" error. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: @Ferit, without seeing this document i can't say anything what is going wrong.  i test my *mwe* again and it works (no errors, no warnings, no bad boxes).  to help you please ask new question or edit this and show how you test/use my *mwe* and see, if we reproduce mentioned error.

Comment: It's weird because I opened a new document in Texstudio and copied your _mwe_ but unfortunately it won't compile as I get the beforementioned errors. :-/

Comment: I was wrong that it did not compile. It compiled with errors but it looks a bit different than your image - see: https://imgur.com/a/M85kL 

I mentioned in the title that I need a longtable landscaped. Is it possible to build the table with longtable and landscape? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: did you have installed recent version of `multirow` package (2016/11/25, version v2.2)?  it seems that its syntax is not recognized. (option `[t]` and option `{=}`) .

Comment: Thank you very much Zarko! That worked and helped me a lot. However, I will have another question for which I will open a new thread.